# Add a Flow in OpenDaylight using Java API

Tags: java, opendaylight

I'm a newbie in opendaylight developing using the java api.
I'm trying to add a simple flow but I can't do it, maybe I can't understand well the documentation.
Can anybody help me?

Comment: How can we help you with your code if you are not showing it? Unfortunately SO is not place where we write tutorials. You need to ask more specific question, describe how you are trying to solve it and what problems/errors you see.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to add a flow would be:

1. Start the controller and point your switch or Open vSwitch / mininet
   instance at the controller on 6633.
2. On the same host as the controller, open a browser to
   http:// localhost :8080
3. Click on the "flows" tab.
4. Add your static flowmod.

Alternatively you can use the API. The following is a PDF that might help you get started. The accompanying video is on the OpenDaylight YouTube channel.

[OpenDaylight Tutorial](http://events.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/slides/Tutorial-Ericsson-RedHat-Juniper.pdf)

-Cheers