# How to write java modules in opendaylight controller

Tags: java, opendaylight

I am a newbie to opendaylight. I have created a topology using mininet and added flows through controller GUI. Now I want to write modules for the same in opendaylight using java. But I dont know how and where should I write it(i.e. in which file). Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: You can download the Hydrogen zip file "Pre-Built Zip File" at OpenDayLight official site. This zip file has the .jars that you need to import in the module that you will develop.

Here is an example of module: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23204630/opendaylight-rest-api-with-java

Comment: Writing a Java Modules means OSGI Modules and that require for you to have some understanding of OSGI,Maven, Equinox and Felix stuff. Please refer to this link : http://www.slideshare.net/esumit/opendaylight-sdn-controller it talks about that.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the structure of some other opendaylight components available in github (just gooogle "github opendaylight"). You will see all the pom.xml files, and structure of the folders which compose an opendaylight component/feature.

Instead of creating all the folders/subfolders, you can use a maven archetype.
For example:

> mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.opendaylight.controller
>   \
>   -DarchetypeArtifactId=opendaylight-startup-archetype \
>   -DarchetypeVersion=1.1.0-SNAPSHOT \
>   -DarchetypeRepository=http://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/opendaylight.snapshot/
>   \
>   -DarchetypeCatalog=http://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/opendaylight.snapshot/archetype-catalog.xml